# Updating ListView from BroadcastReceiver - adapter nullpointerexception

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I have a `BroadcastReceiver` which creates a notification at a set time. When the notification is created, I would like to update my `ListView` which is contained in a `Fragment` called `PendingFragment`. I realise I will only be able to do this is the app is running - that is fine.

So, in my `BroadcastReceiver` I do this:

`PendingFragment.getInstance().updateTheList();`

Then in `PendingFragment` there is the getInstance() method and the updateTheList() method.

```
private static PendingFragment instance;

    public static PendingFragment getInstance() {
        if (null == instance) {

            instance = new PendingFragment();
        }
        return instance;
    }
```

and

```
public void updateTheList() {

        simpleAdpt.refreshMyAdapter();
}
```

The `refreshMyAdapter()` is a sub class of a custom adapter. All it does is remove some items and then calls `simpleAdpt.notifyDataSetChanged();`

My problem is that I have a `nullpointerexception` in `updateTheList()` which presumably means that simpleAdpt is null.  I don't know why as I have that ListView viewable on the screen with items in it - so how can it be null?

Comment: it is advised not to do long term tasks in the receiver as receiver mostly lives for 10 sec or so, so you should perform the task through a service.

Comment: I only create one notification and call the updateTheList() method in my `Fragment`. The method is being called, so I know the problem is not that the receiver has "died".

Comment: then, post the fragment code too, may be someone can find the error there ! :)

Comment: `PendingFragment` is the fragment containing the list? If yes, I don't see why you would expect the `instance` to have valid data members.

Comment: @Luksprog Yes - PendingFragment contains the list. Would you be able to explain the second sentance please :-)

Comment: I think I understand what you said. If I now make `instance = this;` in the onCreateView() of the fragment, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `Luksprog` pointed out in the comments, there was no reason why the `instance` of my `fragment` would have "valid data members".

To solve this, in the `onCreateView()` of the `Fragment`, just put `instance = this;`